# How to config ip address dynamically with spring-security?

Tags: spring-security

I'm new to spring-security, I need to setup a authorization system to secure a REST service.

In my case, my "users" are some servers of different departments and companies.So I tried to config the servers as MyUser which is sub class of UserDetails.

But I got an issue when I was asked to authorize the ip address of the servers. I saw there're ip address authorizations in WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter.configure(HttpSecurity http), and I can retrieve the configuration with configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth){auth.userDetailsService(myUserDetailsService);}. But it seems that the configure(HttpSecurity http) method only runs once when the system boots.

So, what should I do? Is there any way to add a customized checker or something to verify the ip address?

These are my code:

```
public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        // @formatter:off
        http.httpBasic().and()
            .authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/order/**").hasAuthority("read_order") //(1)
            .antMatchers("/order/**").hasIpAddress("192.168.1.45") //(2)
            .anyRequest().denyAll();
        // @formatter:on
    }

    @Override
    protected void configure(AuthenticationManagerBuilder auth) throws Exception {
        auth.userDetailsService(userService);
    }
}
```

With customized `userService` which implements the `UserDetailsService`, I can replace the (1) line with configuration in database. Which means when I change the configuration, Spring Security will load it from database. I don't need to restart the system.

How do I do the similar thing to the (2) line?

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution. I'm not sure is it the best way, but it can work. This is the solution.

First, we can define a class which implements AccessDecisionManager:

```
@Service
public class ResourceAccessDecisionManager implements AccessDecisionManager {
  @Override
    public void decide(Authentication authentication, Object object, Collection<ConfigAttribute> configAttributes)
            throws
            AccessDeniedException, InsufficientAuthenticationException {
//...
        HttpServletRequest request = ((FilterInvocation) object).getHttpRequest();
        String ip = request.getRemoteHost();
        Object principal = authentication.getPrincipal();
        User user;
        if (principal instanceof User){
            user=(User)principal;
            if (!ip.equals(user.getIpConfig())){
                throw new AccessDeniedException("wrong ip");
            }
        }
//...
    }
//...
}
```

Surely, you had to store the ip config within the User class.
Then, we define a class extends AbstractSecurityInterceptor implements Filter:

```
@Service
public class ResourceFilterSecurityInterceptor extends AbstractSecurityInterceptor implements Filter {
//...
    @Autowired
    public void setMyAccessDecisionManager(ResourceAccessDecisionManager resourceAccessDecisionManager) {
        super.setAccessDecisionManager(resourceAccessDecisionManager);
    }

    @Override
    public void doFilter(ServletRequest servletRequest, ServletResponse servletResponse, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws IOException, ServletException {
        FilterInvocation fi = new FilterInvocation(servletRequest, servletResponse, filterChain);
        invoke(fi);
    }

    private void invoke(FilterInvocation fi) throws IOException, ServletException {
        InterceptorStatusToken token = super.beforeInvocation(fi);
        try {
            fi.getChain().doFilter(fi.getRequest(), fi.getResponse());
        } finally {
            super.afterInvocation(token, null);
        }
    }
//...
}
```

And add the filter into security config class:

```
    @Configuration
    @EnableWebSecurity
    public class SecurityConfiguration extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
        private final ResourceService resourceService;
        private final UserService userService;
        private final HttpServletRequest request;
        private final ResourceFilterSecurityInterceptor resourceFilterSecurityInterceptor;
        private final EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig;

        @Autowired
        public SecurityConfiguration(ResourceService resourceService, UserService userService,
                HttpServletRequest request,
                ResourceFilterSecurityInterceptor resourceFilterSecurityInterceptor,
                EnvironmentConfig environmentConfig) {
            this.resourceService = resourceService;
            this.userService = userService;
            this.request = request;
            this.resourceFilterSecurityInterceptor = resourceFilterSecurityInterceptor;
            this.environmentConfig = environmentConfig;
        }

        @Override
        protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
            // @formatter:off
            http
                    .httpBasic().and()
                    .authorizeRequests()
                    .antMatchers("/order/**").authenticated()
                    .anyRequest().authenticated()
                    .and().csrf().disable()
 .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS)
            ;

            http.addFilterBefore(resourceFilterSecurityInterceptor,FilterSecurityInterceptor.class);
            // @formatter:on
        }
    //...
    }
```

Now it can work, but any suggestion is welcome and admirable to improve the solution.